# Can you lose admission/job offer due to few day delay in passport?

Tags: job-search, hiring-process, international, visa

I was recently admitted at a university in Netherlands. I got admission into the Phd program, so I am considered as the employee of the university with salary and every other employment benefit.

I have sent the university all my academic documents. A few days ago, the university contacted me for my passport for visa preparation. I told the university that I am expected to receive my passport on a certain date but there could be a delay of a few days.

The supposed passport receive date came and the passport office did not give me my passport saying that the passport office have not yet received it and I should come after two days to get it.
On the same day I got an email from the university asking me to send the university my passport as the university want to finish the process as soon as possible.

In the absolute worst case the passport office could take 5 more working days but the passport office usually delivers two or three days after the expected date.

Can I lose my job offer due to this delay? I currently told the university  that the passport office has asked me to come after two days but what should I do if the passport office doesn't give me my passport even after two days and further delay giving me my passport by a few more days? The passport office doesn't usually delay giving a passport that long but what should I do if the passport office does create a delay?

Comment: Please reread your question before clicking the Post button. I was an unreadable 'wall of text'. I have edited it for you. And you can always [edit](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/posts/28335/edit) your questions yourself.

Comment: I edited the post further because the indiscriminate use of "they" and "them" made it hard to work out who did what. The post doesn't look elegant after my edit, but I'll take clarity over elegance any day of the week.

Answer (score 8):

Keep the lines of communications with university open. Since the university knows (or should know) that you are waiting for your passport to arrive, make sure to notify the university of any delay.

Make it clear in your phrasing of your communication to the university that the passport office is responsible for the holdup and any corrective action arising from the holdup. For example, don't just say to the university "wait five days", say "I checked with passport office and the passport office told me to wait five days" You want to put the accountability where it belongs, you want to make it clear to the university that you are monitoring the situation closely and that you are doing your best in a bureaucratic situation that is out of your control.

If you are worried about whether you could lose your job/admission over this delay, contact the university directly i.e. phone or show up, ask them the question and get the answer straight from the horses's mouth. I am fairly sure that as far as the university is concerned, you are not nor will you be the last individual who runs into this type of bureaucratic hiccup and that the university will be pretty chill with you about your predicament.

Comment: +1 for "not the last individual who runs into this." Passport / visa troubles are absolutely normal for universities and employers with people from around the world. This happens *all the time.* Just send short notes to them everytime your status changes.

Answer (score 0):

That depends entirely on the organization you're dealing with each time.

They want to receive your passport to finish the paperwork as soon as possible, just contact them (email or phone) and tell them that you're waiting for your passport to arrive to you since there was a delay in the production. Tell them that you'll send it to them as soon as it's finished and that you're sorry for the delay. It's the best (and only) thing to do.

If they're professional then this won't be a problem, as long as you tell them the reason you haven't fulfilled your part of the process. Just waiting and not telling them nothing might have bad consequences, however.

It's more likely than not that they'll be cool about it, the real life doesn't come with no speed-limit barriers. You shouldn't worry too much about this.

Comment: Normally the person doing the paperwork wouldn't be in the position to decide that you lose your admission or don't get your job. They might be in a position to stop you from working until the paperwork is done, if the paperwork is a legal requirement.

Comment: Moral of the story is that he should let them know, there's nothing else he can do. Worrying is pointless if it won't change the outcome.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the university or organization. At my current workplace, we have someone who was supposed to start over a month ago, but hasn't arrived yet due to similar issues. We're still holding that spot for him for whenever he arrives.

Contact the university and tell them everything that's going on. People can be very understanding if you're forthcoming, but if you aren't, it can be very frustrating.